# directory structure for a project that mixes C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++, directory, swig, directory-structure

Say you want want to create a programming project that mixes *C++* and *Python*. The **Foo** *C++* project structure uses *CMake*, and a *Python* module is created by using *Swig*. The tree structure would look something like this:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── FooConfig.cmake.in
├── FooConfigVersion.cmake.in
├── Makefile
├── README
├── foo
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── config.hpp.in
│   ├── foo.cpp
│   └── foo.hpp
└── swig
    └── foo.i
```

Now you would like to make use of the **Foo** project within a *Python* project, say **Bar**:

```
├── AUTHORS.rst
├── CONTRIBUTING.rst
├── HISTORY.rst
├── LICENSE
├── MANIFEST.in
├── Makefile
├── README.rst
├── docs
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── authors.rst
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── contributing.rst
│   ├── history.rst
│   ├── index.rst
│   ├── installation.rst
│   ├── make.bat
│   ├── readme.rst
│   └── usage.rst
├── bar
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── bar.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_bar.py
└── tox.ini
```

This structure was crated by using [cookiecutter's pypackage template](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cookiecutter/0.7.2). A BoilerplatePP template is also available to generate a *CMake* *C++* project using cookiecutter (no *Swig* part).
So now that I have the structure of both projects, and considering that the development will take place mainly in *Python* and the the project will be run in different systems, I need to address the following questions:

1. What's the best way to mix them? Should I collapse both root directories? Should I have the **Foo** *C++* project as a directory of the **Bar** project or the other way around? I may be inclined to put the entire *C++* structure shown above in a folder at the root level of the *Python* project, but I would like to know *a priori* any pitfalls as the *CMake* system is quite powerful and it may be convenient to do it the other way around.
2. In case I decide to put the **Foo** project as a directory within **Bar**, is the *Python* setuptools package as powerful as the *CMake* build system? I ask this because when I take a look at the **Bar** project, at the top level it seems there's only a bunch of scripts, but I don't know if this is the equivalent to *CMake* as I'm new to *Python*.
3. The **Bar** project outlined above has a single *bar* directory, but I assume that whenever this project expands, instead of having many other directories at the root level, other directories containing *Python* code will be placed within *bar*. Is this correct (in the *Pythonic* sense)?
4. I assume that a single egg will be produced from the entire project, so that it can be installed and run in many different python systems. Is the integration of the module created by the **Foo** project easy? I assume that this module will be created in a different directory than *bar*.
5. In order for the *Python* code within the *bar* directory, the module created by *Swig* has to be available, so I guess the most straightforward way to do this is to modify the environmental variable `PYTHONPATH` using the *CMake* system. Is this fine or is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**If the C++ application has no use outside the Python package that will contain it:**

You can pretty safely place the C++ code within the python package that owns it. Have the "foo" directory within the "bar" directory within your example. This will make packaging the final Python module a bit easier.

**If the C++ application is reusable:**

I would definitely try to think of things in terms of "packages", where independent parts are self-contained. All independent parts live on the same level. If one part depends on another, you import from its corresponding "package" from the same level. This is how dependencies typically work.

I would NOT include one within the other, because one does not strictly belong to the other. What if you started a third project that needed "foo", but did not need "bar"?

I would place both "foo" and "bar" packages into the same "project" directory (and I would probably give each package it's own code repository so each package can be easily maintained and installed).

Comment: Actually the Python code _will own_ the C++ project. The latter will be converted to a Python module that will be used by **Bar**.

Comment: Got it. Answer revised.